# Downgrade PHP version from 5.4.9 to 5.3.13 in Ubuntu (13.04) instance

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a server from amazon's ec2 service running on Linux Ubuntu ( Ubuntu Server version: 13.04, 64 bit) and I have installed apache, php, and mysql. The current php version there "5.4.9". I want to upload my previous website there which is based on php version 5.3.13.

I need to downgrade PHP version from 5.4.9 to 5.3.13 in Ubuntu instance.

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the website won't work with 5.4.9? From a security and performance standpoint, it's ill-advised to downgrade. Perhaps with a few changes, the code will work fine?

Comment: @Marcel   The website is based on codeigniter ( version :2.0). When I run it in AWS, few library function not working properly.

Comment: Perhaps it would be worth exploring a CI update. Assuming your app was coded properly, an upgrade should not be hard. Downgrading really, really should be a last resort, especially for a production site.